# Trigger two Div's on hover on first?

Tags: html, css

I got one div containing an animation(.animation) and another div just containing an background image(.image).Now i want to trigger the both div's using another div(.start) . But somehow im confused how to do it.

html

```
<div class="start">

< /div">
```

CSS

```
.start{

width:87px;
height:189px;
position:absolute; 
float: left;
margin-top: 477px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: green;

}

.start:hover~.animation,.start:hover~.name



.animation
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute; 
float: left;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: red;
....

}
.image
{
width:30px;
height:300px;
position:absolute; 
float: left;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
background-color: green;

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by trigger????what effect do you want???

Comment: Well if im hovering over the Div "Start" so far i got it working to trigger one div with .start:hover which contained an animation (blinking) for example.Now im trying to trigger another Div the same time which is just containing an image. So on hover i get one div with an nimation and a div with just an image at the same time ;)

Comment: Please let us know if our answers helped you

Answer (score 2):

Make `.animation` and `.image` invisible by default:

```
.animation, .image {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, you'll have to show them whenever `.start` is hovered.

### CSS way

Using your own technique:

```
.start:hover~.animation, .start:hover~.image {
    display: initial;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vas4hyrj/

Though this will work *only* if `.animation` and `.image` are placed after `.start`

### JQuery way

```
$(".start").hover(function() {
    //Show the divs when mouse hovers
    $(".animation, .image").css("display", "initial");
}, function() {
    //Hide divs when mouse stops to hover
    $(".animation, .image").css("display", "none");
});
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cw0fgxnt/

And that one will always work, no matter what; but it uses JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If your element is a first sibling of .start, you can use the + selector, otherwise you'll have to use jQuery.